What is the best way to use Tortoise ORM in Celery tasks?
I am using Tortoise ORM with my FastAPI application. Due to the nature of my application, I require Celery to execute almost a dozen tasks, most of which involve some sort of database operations. Since I am managing databases using Tortoise ORM in my FastAPI application, I want to use it in my Celery tasks as well. However, running asynchronous Tortoise ORM functions from synchronous Celery tasks have been tricky, to say the least. I have tried multiple approaches to run the asynchronous functions, including

Wrapping the entire code in an async method and calling that method using asyncio.run(coro(*args, **kwargs)) from the Celery task.
Using the run_async method of the Tortoise ORM library.
Using the following method
def run_async_method_in_celery(coro, *args, **kwargs):
  try:
      loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  except RuntimeError:
      loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
      asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
  else:
      if loop.is_closed():
          loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
          asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

  return loop.run_until_complete(coro(*args, **kwargs))


Using async_to_sync of the asgiref library.

None of these approaches worked 100% of the time. Very often I would encounter a RuntimeError or a ConnectionError from the asyncpg library used by Tortoise ORM for PostgreSQL databases. Sometimes the tasks would run perfectly if called after one execution of it is complete. However, if they are called multiple times in a matter of seconds, they start producing exceptions.
Is there any full-proof way to use Tortoise ORM with Celery? Or should I just stop trying to accomplish this?
Any help and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

What errors have you been encountering? The ConnectionError doesn't sound like it has to do with sync/async, at least not directly.

I have encountered ConnectionError as well as InterfaceError and ConnectionDoesNotExistError in cases where I have multiple tasks running concurrently, or even multiple insert or update queries with in_transaction inside a for loop where when one task or operation was done executing the Tortoise ORM functionality and it closed the database connection while the others were in the middle of operation. I have not explicitly called any connection closing method anywhere on my codebase. As I understand it, I could be wrong, that the library handles connections itself when performing operations.
